# ubuntu USB wont save my setting on reboot despite my 2gb persistent partition

Tags: usb, persistence

Ive install Ubuntu 13.0.4 onto a new 8gb USB drive with the windows universal installer.
I told it to format the drive and leave a 2gb persistent space.

It all seemed to work.

On boot I select try ubuntu form usb. It boots everything is fine.

When I reboot however it doesn't save and changes I make.

This is very frustrating ive reinstalled 10 times and ive tried 3 different usb sticks.
Ive also tried using the ubuntu startup disk installer app running from the usb version of ubuntu.

Nothing works. I dont want to have to go out and buy a damn hard drive because the project im trying to set up doesn't need one.

Comment: I run across a lot of complaints about Universal installer, Try Startup Disk Creator from the Live CD or UNetbootin.

Answer (score 0):

You might bebefit from INSTALLING it to the usb drive.

1. Set up a usb drive with the installer.
2. Boot with both usb drives in the computer from the drive you put the installer on.
3. Select install, then "something else" from the menu
4. Pick out your 8gig usb drive to install to.
5. Be SURE to put grub on that (8gig) drive. -ie /dev/sdb not, for example /dev/sdb1
6. It will take longer to install, but you will have a 'real' install on the 8gig drive now.